# Multiple synchronized MediaPlayers

Tags: android

I am developing a musical application that plays several sounds all together, like a sort of multitrack program. A timer triggers when it's the moment for all the sounds to play. Sounds have to be played exactly on the beat and perfectly synchronized and mixed.

The easiest solution i found is to have one MediaPlayer for each sound, initialize all of them at the very beginning, with MediaPlayer.create() inside my app's OnCreate().
To make it more reliable and quick I made TWO mediaplayers for each sound.
Then I have a timer that calls simple loop, similar to this:

```
for (int w=0; w<SOUNDS; w++)
    if (must_play(w)) {
        if (mp[w].isPlaying()) {
            if (mp2[w].isPlaying())
                mp[w].seekTo(0);
            else mp2[w].start();
        } else mp[w].start();
    }
```

I used .seekTo(0) because I found it slightly faster than making .stop() and .start().
But the sounds are not always perfectly synchronized. A 1/10 of second of delay between the .start() of two mediaplayers is very annoying if those two sounds are two drums that are supposed to play perfectly in line.
Is there a way to force all mediaplayers that are instructed to .start() to effectly play all at once?
Please note that the sounds may be very short, like drum sounds: the problem is not to keep the multiple media players synchronized over time, but to make them start exactly all together, without delay.

The question is rather tricky because in my opinion involves two problems:

- Prioritization, above other processes that may slow down the timer or the app itself.
- How to create a single command/object/method (or whatever) that runs all the sounds atomically.

Thank you.

Comment: I do not think that multiple instances of a mediaplayer will stay synchronized over time, as they all use their own internal timing mechanisms. For these kind of applications you need a (custom) mediaplayer that is able to play multiple tracks using the same timing mechanism...

Comment: Please note that I'm talking about very short audio files, like drum sounds, the problem is not the synchronization over time, but make them start exactly at the same time. I add this clarification in the main post.

Comment: Hello? Have you found the answer? Have exactly the same problem with track sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it, just used the SoundPool class instead of MediaPlayer. It's much more responsive, and handles very well multitracks, even cutting the oldest sound played if the streams are not enough. Although the questions weren't answered, the problem is fixed.